# Storing firestore document reference in NgRx throws error

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am creating a project with Ionic, Angular, Firebase and NgRx and I have a problem when I try to storing document reference inside the NgRx store.

My Code:

**Component**

```
loginUser() {
  let loginFormValue = this.loginForm.value;
  this.authStore.dispatch(login({
    email: loginFormValue.email,
    password: loginFormValue.password,
    rememberMe: loginFormValue.rememberMe
  }));
}
```

**Effect**

```
login$ = createEffect(() => {
  return this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(login),
    switchMap((action) => {
      return this.authenticationService.loginUserByEmail(action.email, action.password, action.rememberMe).pipe(
          map((user) => {
            return loginSucceeded({ user });
          }),
          catchError((message) => {
            return of(loginFailed({ message }));
          })
      );
    })
  );
});
```

**Service**

```
loginUserByEmail(email: string, password: string, rememberMe: boolean): Observable<User> {
  let persistence = rememberMe ? auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL : auth.Auth.Persistence.NONE;
  return new Observable( (observer: Subscriber<User>) => {
    this.angularFireAuth.setPersistence(persistence).then(() => {
      this.angularFireAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((userCredential: auth.UserCredential) => {
        this.angularFirestore.collection('users').doc(userCredential.user.uid).get().toPromise().then((doc: DocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>) => {
          let data: DocumentData = doc.data();
          if (data) {
            data.id = uid;
            data.ref = doc.ref;
          }
          observer.next(data);
          observer.complete();
         });
      });
    });
  });
}
```

As you can see after getting the actual data from the document I'm storing the `ref` on the actual data for later use. In addition, this data also contains other references to other documents.

So I am actually getting the user document from the service with all properties including the `ref` property but after dispatching the `loginSucceeded` action this error throwed in the console: `Cannot read property 'ignoreUndefinedProperties' of undefined`.

I didn't find solution / workaround for this.

Hope you can help me, Thanks!